# Segmentation Foult in array of Linked lists

Tags: c++, data-structures

I've been implementing UnionFind data-structure, and in overloaded ostream << operator I wanted to use dynamicly allocated array of linked lists (witch i have implemented previously). The problem is that I'm getting some wierd behaviors and seg-foults, and I can't figure out why. While debbuging I have added line 34 (std::cout << out[0];), witch throws seg foult. The interrestning thing is that that printing LinkedList 0 (pom[0]), works until last iterration of main for loop (for (int k = 0; k < this->size(); k++)), witch sugessts that the problem is in LinkedList class... Any ideas why?

zbiory_rozlaczne.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class UnionFind
{
    struct Element
    {
        T val;
        int set_id, children;
        UnionFind<T>::Element &operator=(UnionFind<T>::Element &el)
        {
            this->val = el.val;
            this->set_id = el.set_id;
            this->children = el.children;
            return *this;
        }
    };
    long unsigned int union_size, memory_size;
    Element *Union;
    std::ostream &print_me(std::ostream &os);

public:
    // void print_me();
    UnionFind();
    void test();

    int size();
    ~UnionFind();

    template <class U>
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, UnionFind<U> &);
};

#include <zbiory_rozlaczne.cpp>
```

zbiory_rozlaczne.cpp

```
#include "zbiory_rozlaczne.h"
#include "lista_jednokierunkowa.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
std::ostream &UnionFind<T>::print_me(std::ostream &os)
//void UnionFind<T>::print_me()
{
    LinkedList<int> path;
    LinkedList<int> *out = new LinkedList<int>[this->size()];
    bool *been{new bool[this->size()]{false}};
    for (int k = 0; k < this->size(); k++)
    {
        if (!been[k])
        {
            path.push_back(k);
            been[k] = true;
        }
        int pom = this->Union[k].set_id;
        while (this->Union[pom].set_id != pom)
        {
            if (!been[pom])
            {
                path.push_back(pom);
                been[pom] = true;
            }
            pom = Union[pom].set_id;
        }
        for (unsigned int l = 0; l < path.size(); l++)
        {
            std::cout << out[0] << " ";
            std::cout << "pom " << pom << " " << Union[path[l]].val << "\n";
            out[pom].push_back(Union[path[l]].val);
            std::cout << out[pom] << "\n\n";
        }
        path.clear();
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < this->size(); k++)
    {
        os << "{";
        /*if (out[k].size())
            os << out[k][0];*/
        //os << out[k];
        //os << out[k].size();
        /*for (unsigned int l = 1; l < out[k].size(); l++)
            os << "," << out[k][l];*/
        os << "}";
    }

    delete[] out;
    delete[] been;
    return os;
}

template <class T>
UnionFind<T>::UnionFind()
{
    this->union_size = 4;
    this->memory_size = 4;
    this->Union = new UnionFind<T>::Element[4];
    Union[0].val = 1;
    Union[1].val = 2;
    Union[2].val = 3;
    Union[3].val = 4;

    Union[0].set_id = 0;
    Union[1].set_id = 0;
    Union[2].set_id = 1;
    Union[3].set_id = 3;
}

template <class T>
void UnionFind<T>::test()
{
    for (int k = 0; k < this->union_size; k++)
    {
        std::cout << this->Union[k].set_id << " ";
    }
}

template <class T>
int UnionFind<T>::size()
{
    return this->union_size;
}

template <class T>
UnionFind<T>::~UnionFind()
{
    delete[] this->Union;
}

template <class U>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, UnionFind<U> &obj)
{

    return obj.print_me(os);
}
```

lista_jednokierunkowa.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
    template <class U>
    struct node
    {
        U value;
        node<U> *next;
        node()
        {
            next = nullptr;
        }
    };
    node<T> *head, *tail;
    unsigned int list_size;

public:
    LinkedList();
    void push_back(T obj);
    int size();
    bool clear();
    bool is_empty();
    ~LinkedList();

    T &operator[](int);
    template <class U>
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, LinkedList<U> &);
};

#include <lista_jednokierunkowa.cpp>
```

lista_jednokierunkowa.cpp

```
#include "lista_jednokierunkowa.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
    this->list_size = 0;
    this->head = nullptr;
    this->tail = nullptr;
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::push_back(T obj)
{
    node<T> *pom = new node<T>;
    pom->value = obj;
    pom->next = this->head;
    this->head = pom;
    this->list_size++;
    if (this->list_size == 2)
        this->tail = this->head->next;
}

template <class T>
int LinkedList<T>::size()
{
    return this->list_size;
}

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::clear()
{
    if (!this->list_size)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    node<T> *pom1;
    for (node<T> *pom = this->head; pom != nullptr; pom = pom1)
    {
        pom1 = pom->next;
        delete pom;
        pom->next = nullptr;
    }
    this->list_size = 0;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
    //std::cout << "wtf";
    this->clear();
}

template <class T>
T &LinkedList<T>::operator[](int index)
{
    node<T> *pom = this->head;
    for (int x = 0; x < index; x++)
        pom = pom->next;
    return pom->value;
}

template <class U>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, LinkedList<U> &obj)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < obj.size(); x++)
        os << obj[x] << " ";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Have you used your debugger?  Segfaults are usually pretty easy to track down with a debugger.

Comment: Don't #include .cpp files

Comment: You get segmentation fault? It should not compile because of circular include `lista_jednokierunkowa.h` with `lista_jednokierunkowa.cpp`.

Comment: Including .cpp file inside .h file was a hacky solution to templates promlem described heare: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/How-to-Define-a-Template-Class-in-a-h-File-and-Imp

Answer (score 0):

Some things I noticed (not a complete answer):

- Why the file `zbiory_rozlaczne.h` is same as `lista_jednokierunkowa.h`?
- In the list's `clear()` method you do

  ```
        delete pom;
        pom->next = nullptr;
  ```

The second line is not necessary and it triggers undefined behavior by writing to a deallocated object location.

- In the `operator[]` you do not validate the argument against the list's length.

Comment: 1st problem is my mistake in copying, sory for that, and thanks for tips. I'm also not sure how to behave when i'm giving index >= length of my list to [] operator so I left it as it is.